# Retrieving Column comments using MySQL ODBC driver

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I am using the following function call to retrieve the REMARKS of a column of my **MySQL** table.

```
SQLBindCol(st_handle,12, SQL_C_WCHAR,comment,512-1, &l);
```

But comment is always an empty string.All other columns are retrieved.

I am working on windows and using **mysql ODBC 5.2**.

For oracle **ODBC** i need to set **CatalogOptions=1**

Reference:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19531-01/817-2514-10/GlossaryContext11.html

Is there a similar setting to be done for mysql odbc driver?